# C++ std::fill and std::fill_n error "error C2679"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, std

***What I'm trying to do:***

I'm working in a code which is not mine and I'm trying to refactor this. There I have a struct type object, let's call it **MY_STRUCTURE** with some parameters inside. In the old version of that code, they are using memset to initialize the structure with 0 in all parameters. So, I've tried to change that memset to a more c++ standard approach which is fill or fill_n.

Also, I should mention... There is not an array, is just an object, so all that I'm trying to do is to initialize that object with 0 everywhere.

The memset approach which is working perfectly fine looks like

```
this:memset(&MyScruct, 0, sizeof(MyScruct));
```

***What have I tried:***

I'm trying to use one of fill and fill_n like this:

```
std::fill(&MyScruct, &MyScruct+ sizeof(MyScruct), 0);
```

and also

```
std::fill_n(&MyScruct, sizeof(MyScruct), 0);
```

where MyScruct is `MY_STRUCT MyScruct`;

In both of this cases I'm getting the same error:

> error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Do you have any idea why or what's happening here?

Comment: `fill` and `fill_n` expect to "fill" an array, as if by doing `= 0;` for each element in the array.  I am guess you actually want to set each byte of your struct to 0;  if so then `fill` and `fill_n` are not the right tool

Comment: It would improve the question to explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: What is `MY_STRUCT`?

Comment: It's happening because `fill` is trying to do the equivalent of `*&MyScruct = 0;`.

Comment: Try an old good memset.

Comment: So is no way to make it works just with fill or fill_n?

Comment: @DumitruVlad This is not what `fill` is for - it is not a "C++-flavoured" `memset`.

Comment: fill functions are templates. You're trying to set bytes, therefore you must pass them bytes addresses, not MyStruct addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original code, `memset` will completely ignore the type system and just write bytes to raw memory, trashing whatever was there before (and I have to question whether the *"memset approach which is working perfectly fine"* actually works fine, or is really undefined).

On the other hand, `std::fill` works with the type system, and sets values of the right type. `0` is not a value of the right type (and is not assignable to the type), so you can't "fill" the struct with zeros.

> There is not an array, is just an object

Then you **definitely** don't want to pass `sizeof(MyStruct)` because that says how many objects of the type to "fill". You only have **one** object, not an array with `sizeof(MyStruct)` elements.

`sizeof(MyStruct)` is the right argument for `memset` because that works with bytes, not objects. You need to tell `memset` how many bytes to write. But it's totally wrong for `std::fill` and `std::fill_n` which count in objects, not bytes (unless by chance `sizeof(MyStruct)==1`, but even then it's a bug waiting to happen).

> I've tried to change that memset to a more c++ standard approach which is fill or fill_n

`std::fill` and `std::fill_n` are the C++ way to assign new values to a sequence of values, not the C++ version of `memset`. The C++ version of `memset` is `memset`!

If you're not trying to *reset* the values of the struct, just initialize it, then the correct way is just:

```
MyStruct s = { };
```

This is perfectly valid C++ and works in any version, from C++98 up to the latest standard. This is simpler and safer and more readable than using `memset`.

Comment: "I have to question whether the "memset approach which is working perfectly fine" actually works fine, or is really undefined": could you elaborate on this? It's safe for POD types, right?

Comment: @joe_chip it's safe for trivially-copyable types. All POD types are trivially-copyable. We don't know if the OP's type is a POD though.

Answer (score 3):

If the code was written with `memset` correctly then there is no reason to change it.  `fill` is not a substitute for `memset`.

In modern C++ it would be bad to *design* a class to require `memset`. However if you are *using* someone else's class that was designed that way,  it is correct to use their class as it was designed.

---

In modern C++ you would design the class so that value-initialization resets it:

```
MyScruct = MY_STRUCT{};
```

This code may or may not have the same effect as `memset`, depending on the details of `MY_STRUCT`.

Comment: I've tried already this but is not working because they are not using c++11, I think... they are using c++03.

Comment: @DumitruVlad i would recommend just not changing the original code.

Comment: how about assigning 0/default values to `MY_STRUCT` members in default constructor? Wouldn't it give same effect as `MyScruct = MY_STRUCT{};`?

Comment: @miradham he might not want to change the class definition; and even so, that introduces another possible point of failure (e.g. maybe you forget to set one of the members)

Comment: short answer @miradham, I'm not able to do that because I'm not allowed to change that code.